# Using back when the location is not the same

Tags: grammar, meaning

> The hamster jumped onto her from your shoulder and jumped back onto
> you.

This is ok, because the location is the same, but sometimes it's not the same.

> The hamster jumped onto her from your shoulder and jumped back into your armpit.

Is this ok? Can we still use armpit if it has never been there?

> The water from lake A in Canada was flowing to lake B in the U.S. and was diverted back to lake C in Canada.

Is this ok? How would you say this?

Comment: This might be clearer: "The hamster jumped onto her from your shoulder and then back to you: this time to your armpit." Your 'lakes' sentence Is a strange mixture of the simple and continuous past tenses. Making it all the same you could say, "The water was flowing from lake A in Canada to lake B in the US. It was then being diverted back to Canada: to lake C." Or "The water flowed from lake A in Canada to lake B in the US where it was diverted back to Canada: to lake C."

Comment: I'm not sure anything much can jump **into** an armpit. It's sounds so awkward I wonder if it's worth saying.

Comment: It's fine because it means the place being referenced as the same is the larger place, not the smaller part of it: the hamster returns to "you" and the water returns to Canada.